# Как отловить ответ BAD_REQUEST во Vue JS

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js

Не могу понять один момент. У меня есть Rest API, который возвращает экземпляр некоторого класса в случае успеха, и `ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);` в случае ошибки, например при падении БД.

Я хочу отловить этот ответ и вывести подсказку об этом. В моем vue файле я определил функцию `addItemToCart`

```
addItemToCart(variation) {
    try {
        console.log("Try Section")
        carts.add(variation).then((response, rej) => {
            if (response) {
                console.log("Response")
                if (response.bodyText == "anonymous") {
                    window.location.href = "/login"
                } else if (response.bodyText == variation.id) {
                    this.snackbar = true
                }
            } else if (rej) {
                console.log('Error')
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error")
    }
}
```

Как видно, вызовы `console.log(...)` расставлены везде, где возможно. Однако в случае возвращения `ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);` не срабатывает ни один из трех конечных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть после `Try Section` не вызывается ни один `console.log(...)`. Вопрос, как мне отловить этот статус в моей функции?

Comment: Предположу, что нужен обработчик `.catch` после `.then`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko,  это действительно помогло, опубликуйте пожалуйста свой ответ, отмечу его как решение моей проблемы.